# How to pass variable/parameter to android view method

Tags: android, methods, view, components

I am new to StackOverFlow and JAVA.
Ignore `catch`
This is working fine.

```
public int GetHeight (AndroidViewComponent Component) {
        try {
            return Component.getView().getHeight();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return -0000;
        }
    }
```

I am getting build error with this.

```
public int GetMethod (AndroidViewComponent Component , string get) {
        try {
            return Component.getView().get();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return -0000;
        }
    }
```

I want to reduce code.
If, else if,..... else
So I want to pass the `get` parameter directly to the method.

```
Component.getView().get();
```

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot pass name of method to be accessed in the parameter of the function, as when you compile your code, all the method names are renamed to random variables, to prevent hacking. So no dynamic call to variable names.

Unless, you do if/else from the string parameters and call the method that way. Example:-

```
public int GetXonScreen (AndroidViewComponent Component, String nameOfMethod) {
        try {
            int[] location = new int[2];
            if (nameOfMethod == "height") {
              return Component.getView().getHeight();
            } else if (nameOfMethod == "width") {
              return Component.getView().getWidth();
            } else {return 0;}
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return -0000;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is giving this compile error. `missing return statement` It is not accepting `return` with if...else

Comment: Yes, you need to add final else, just in case if no if is selected, then some default return statement should be returned